# How does cloudstor relocation work

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm having a weird problem using docker-for-aws and cloudstor.
So I manually create 2 volumes using cloudstor like this

```
docker volume create \
  -d "cloudstor:aws" \
  --opt ebstype=gp2 \
  --opt size=15 \
  --opt iops=180 \
  --opt backing=relocatable \
  ci_ping3-1-vol

docker volume create \
  -d "cloudstor:aws" \
  --opt ebstype=gp2 \
  --opt size=15 \
  --opt iops=180 \
  --opt backing=relocatable \
  ci_ping3-2-vol
```

And I use a stack called ci to test it

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  ping3:
    image: alpine
    command: ping docker.com
    volumes:
      - ping_vol:/mydata
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
volumes:
  ping_vol:
    external:
      name: "{{.Service.Name}}-{{.Task.Slot}}-vol"
```

My swarm consist on 1 manager and 1 worker (just for testing). Then, I exec a bash inside each replica and modify a file in the `/mydata` folder. I go to the aws console and kill the working instance, forcing the service to relocate. When I look in my EBS console I can see how a second drive is created when the volume needs to move from AZ, but once the service is running again, the data inside `/mydata` is not what I was expecting.

I triend manually calling `sync` before terminating the machine, I tried to scale down to force a more graceful service termination but the result on `/mydata` is never what I expected. Weirdly enough, it seems that some times the data is filled with contents from older test... so I don't even know how to debug this :(